# Show that $x^*AA^*x=x^*A^*Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n×n}$, then $A$ is normal if and only if for every $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n×1}$, $x^*AA^*x=x^*A^*Ax$.

Part of my proof: Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n×n}$ be Hermitian, and let $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ be the least and greatest eigenvalue of $A$ respectively. Then, $\lambda_{min}\leq x^*Ax\leq\lambda_{max}$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: what does $*$ mean?

Comment: To typset $x^*$ use `x^*`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was used to $x*$, didn't know they're different here. But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is normal, then $AA^* = A^* A$ so $x^* AA^* x = x^* A^* Ax$ holds immediately.

---

It remains to prove the other direction: suppose $x^* A A^* x = x^* A^* A x$ for all $x$.
Let $B := AA^* - A^* A$. Note that the assumption can be rewritten as $x^* B x = 0$ for all $x$, and proving normality of $A$ is equivalent to proving $B=0$.

**Hint**: To show $B=0$, prove that $B$ symmetric ($B^* = B$) and skew-symmetric ($B^* = -B$).

> It is immediate that $B^* = B$. However, the assumption also implies $B^* = -B$, since $$e_i^* B e_i = 0$$ for any $i$, and $$0 = (e_i + e_j)^* B (e_i + e_j) = B_{i,j} + B_{j,i}$$ for $i \ne j$. Thus, $B = B^* = -B$ so $B = 0$ and $A$ is normal.